# In pari-gp, how to find a primitive element of finite field?

Tags: pari, pari-gp, finite-field

Say, I want a finite field containing `q^n` elements for some `prime q` and `positive n`. How to **get** its **primitive element**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get some primitive element with the following code:

```
var = 'x; \\ sets a variable in the polynomial representation of finite field
f = ffgen(ffinit(q, n)); \\ GF(q^n) ~ GF(q)[x]/<f(x)>. Note `f` is just an irreducible
a = ffprimroot(f); \\ gets a root `a` of `f`
poly = minpoly(a, var); \\ finds a minimal polynomial for `a`
primitive_elt = ffgen(poly, var); \\ finds a root of the minimal polynomial

\\ assertion: check the order
fforder(primitive_elt) == q^n-1
```

Note, that the finite field can have certain primitive elements. The code above finds random any. Please, note that the code above assumes `n` > 1. Otherwise, the function `minpoly` crashes (tested with PARI/GP 2.7.2 32-bit).

Comment: Could you please kindly help me. Let `n = m * p`. How to get a primitive element of `GF(q^n)` as a m-dimensional vector over `GF(q^p)`?

Comment: @aka_test: To reach your goal you have to calculate the minimal polynomial of `GF(q^n)` as a polynomial over `GF(q^p)`. Please, see the http://johnkerl.org/doc/ffcomp.pdf (section 6.1) for details.